# GCLB Missing SameSite and Secure Flags

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I am facing an issue with GCLB which is running with instance groups. I have multiple instances running in the backend. On the web server, headers are set up properly like `SameSite=None; HttpOnly; Secure` but in GCP load balancer only `HttpOnly` flag is coming. Please see the screenshot [image: screenshot].

Answer (score 1):

Potentially this is related to different feature requests for Google Cloud Load Balancer.

[Feature for allowing users to update/edit response header with External HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://issuetracker.google.com/178375246)

[Using session_affinity cookie with SameSite attribute](https://issuetracker.google.com/147688908)

[Ability to set the session cookie as Secure when using Generated cookie session affinity](https://issuetracker.google.com/137831004)

In my personal experience, GCP support mentions that this is tracked by their develop team and there is no ETA for applying them, this based on [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) doc.